# Creating a Predominance Visualization in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping

[This](https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/languagesofaustralia.com/public/language.html) is what I'd like to replicate. I'd like to show the **dominant category** for each region. Like the author, I also have 6 categories to show (languages).

Here is the [article](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/mapping/creating-a-predominance-visualization-with-arcade/) that is explaining his method. How do I go about replicating this for QGIS?

[image]

Comment: It's one of basic of qgis. Follow some tutorial to improve the use of this quality tool. Some article are well documented https://mesange.educagri.fr/htdocs/sigea/supports/QGIS/distance/perfectionnement/M03_AnalyseThematique_gen_web/co/10_N2_Classer_Colonne_Alphanumerique.html

Comment: Can you explain what your data looks like? I'm assuming you have a POPULATION count column for each of the languages? I do this using SQL, which isn't necessarily available for QGIS (we use PostgreSQL with PostGIS)...

Comment: @DPSSpatial Yes I do. It looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/jNPepIF)

Comment: This is how it is done on the ArcGIS side - https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/map-multiple-attributes-at-once-using-predominance/  This will be do-able in QGIS.